# IIS7 Error 500 randomly

Tags: iis

[IIS error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGtI1.png)

My Asp.net website already launch around 3 months.
recently the website start happen error HTTP 500.

The weird thing is, the error is happen randomly. Mostly after add, delete update, the error will happen. Everything when i saw this error, i will go to IIS and restart the IIS, the website miraculously all right. But now, the website is getting more and more frequently.

I tried to figure it out where is the problem. the debugging message didn't give me much value info(Refer screenshot). I have put some log into the project.
and the try catch error log show

> Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10048)

it doesn't make any sense to me, why this issue can cure by restart IIS.
and now i'm totally no idea how to trace with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever your application faces an unhandled exception you will get the "500" error code which simply states that an "error" has occurred.
This can happen due to any anything from inability to connect to your database to an unhandled exception being thrown.
To troubleshoot this and get more details about the error :
1 - Check the windows event viewer 
2 - try implementing the application_error method in your global.asax to get a more details about the error (here is a quick demo to how to do this : 
(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx)